# C# Вывод даных в datagridview с другого потока

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, datagridview

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. Есть класс "NetworkModel" в котором, создается поток для прослушивания сокета, и данные которые приходят необходимо вывести в таблицу, которая находиться на главной форме. Даные приходят, но в таблице не отображаються.
Ниже Класс NetworkModel и сама функция вывода в таблицу.

```
VekForm vekForm = new VekForm();

public void Connect(byte[] ip_adress, int port)
        {
            string _ip = BitConverter.ToString(ip_adress);
            
            client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", port);
            stream = client.GetStream();
            
            MessageBox.Show("Client success connect to Server");
            TCPThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TCPClientRecieve));
            TCPThread.Start();
        }


        public void TCPClientRecieve()
        {
            while (client.Connected)
            {
                int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                response.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                                
                Console.WriteLine("+");

                String responseData = String.Empty;
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

                if (data[0] == 0)
                {
                    vekForm.BasicFrameDataTable(data);
                }
                if (data[0] == 1)
                {
                    vekForm.FrameDataLocationStation(data);
                }
            }
        }
```

и сама форма главного окна программы с функцией которая вызывается высше

```
 public void BasicFrameDataTable(byte[] _basicFrame)
        {
            float Freq = BitConverter.ToSingle(_basicFrame, 1);
            float Tau = BitConverter.ToSingle(_basicFrame, 5);
            float Pulse = BitConverter.ToSingle(_basicFrame, 9);
            AddDataToDGV(Freq, Tau, Pulse);
        }

public void AddDataToDGV(float _Freq, float _Tau, float _Pulse)
        {
            
            dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate                                                                                                 
            {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("123", _Freq.ToString(), _Tau.ToString(), _Pulse.ToString());
                }));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Для начала BitConverter.ToSingle(_basicFrame, 1) - начинать надо с 0. dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate - это зачем?

Comment: `dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView1.Rows.Add("123", _Freq.ToString(), _Tau.ToString(), _Pulse.ToString())));`

Comment: `VekForm vekForm = new VekForm();` - быть может в этом проблема, вы создаете дубликат формы, а не работаете с уже существующией. Проблема за пределами показанного кода, и многопоточка тут вообще не при чем. Учите ООП. `VekForm vekForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<VekForm>().First();` - костыль конечно, но зато простой.